# PHP Download file from non-hosted directory

Tags: php

I've been able to upload a file through PHP to a non-hosted directory (directory is not on the website) with read/write permissions for the PHP file (www). How would I download the file from this directory? I've been able to list the contents of the directory, but clicking on the files (made the filenames links) does not work as the computer attempts to download the file from the path on the server. I'm new to PHP, so all help is appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit:** Before I get down votes for this being a broad question, I just want to know how to access the files in the non-hosted directory and pass them to the user. I already know how to download normal files hosted on the website. Thanks!

Comment: @minitech I set the target to ../../../../uploads (this is out of the hosted directory), set a file for the upload key, and have the PHP file place the file in the target directory. This works because the PHP file has direct access to the directory on the server. A normal user does not have access to the directory, so I somehow need to "pass" the file to them.

Comment: And reading it back is more trouble? Well, I posted an answer, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a delegating PHP file for file access. I don't know anything about your structure, but if you can write it, you can (presumably) read it back with [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents):

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents('/the/path/to/the/unhosted/directory/file.ext');
?>
```